# How to get selected text from select tag using event listener?

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<select id='alpha'>
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const select_node = document.getElementById('alpha');
select_node.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
console.log(e.target.value); // get selected value.
   },false);
```

I am getting selected value but how can I get **selected text** ?
I have tried google but nothing found anything.
So How can I get selected text using event listener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text
```

[`.options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) property collects all of the `<select>` `<option>`s

[`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property returns the current index number of selected `<option>`

`.text` property of course is the text within an `<option>TEXT</option>`

or here's an easier way:

```
e.target.selectedOptions[0].text;
```

[`.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) property is `.options` and `.selectedIndex` together.

```js
const select_node = document.getElementById('alpha');
select_node.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value); // get selected value.
  console.log(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text); // get selected text.
  console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].text); // get selected text an easier way.
}, false);
```

```html
<select id='alpha'>
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please help me here too [animation not working for the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406368/animation-not-working-for-the-second-time)

Comment: @Abhishekkamal does any of these answers resolve your question? If so, accept one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the dropwdown's `options` at the dropdown's `selectedIndex`:

```js
var select_node = document.getElementById("alpha");
select_node.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
   console.log(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text); // get selected value.
});
```

Comment: how does `.value` return the selected *text* ?

Comment: Well, change .value to .text if you want the content instead of whats in the value attribute. Updated accordingly.

Comment: thanks but I want to get select text by using **e** parameter.

Comment: then use e.target instead of selected_node: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text

Comment: @marks please help me [animation not working for the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406368/animation-not-working-for-the-second-time)